# google-cloud-services unable to connect any service

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

currently i can not access and services of my VM, browser SSH connections, 443 and 80 ports are not answering any requests. First i thought, somehow my TCP ports closed but then when i check them i realised they are active. Is there any person had same issue as like mine at past ?

I could'nt gave more techinal informations currently cuz of my less knowledge about managing VM's. If you ask me some results or response of tricks ill be there for get results and share on here.

Regarts from Turkey, thanks for all kind entrys.

Comment: A common reason is the public IP address changed when you started your instance. Check if your VM is using static or ephemeral IP addresses. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses

Comment: Yes, our ip address changed to another class, but still i can not connect any service except ssh on my instance

Comment: Review the logs for your applications/service and Stackdriver for warnings and errors. A common problem is hardcoded IP addresses but I can only guess with the details provided. Now that you can SSH into your instance, you have the access to debug the problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley https://prnt.sc/10cg85v

Comment: Also: https://prnt.sc/10cg8q1

Comment: Your screenshot only shows part of what you did. Copy and paste the text into your question. Tip: do not use external picture sites. Stackoverflow supports pictures in your question.

Comment: Thanks for that information, i didnt know, btw i tried connect with googlecloud shell to and it doesnt works.

Comment: ```
Welcome to Cloud Shell! Type "help" to get started.
Your Cloud Platform project in this session is set to organic-cat-299714.
Use “gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]” to change to a different project.
sinemkozmetik@cloudshell:~ (organic-cat-299714)$ gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "europe-west3-c" "yupari" --project "organic-cat-299714"
```

Comment: Connect to your instance using the serial port and look for entries related to your SSH server and ssh login attempts. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console